# Can I put a bound on the number of elements that contribute to "most of the sum"?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, upper-lower-bounds

Given $\epsilon > 0$ and sequence $\{a_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ where $a_k > 0$ for all $k$ and
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k = A > \epsilon,$$
I know that I can find a finite set $K\subset \mathbb{N}\ \ |\ \ |K| = N,$ such that
$$\sum_{k\notin K}a_k\leq \epsilon. $$
My question is if I can put a loose bound on $N$? My intuition is that for most $k\in \mathbb{N},$ $a_k \leq \frac{1}{k},$ and so I've hoped I could somehow show that I can find $K$ such that $N = O\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}\right).$

My apologizes if its a trivial question, I don't remember much of calculus/analysis.

Comment: So you want to find the set $K\subset \mathbb{N}\ $ with fewest elements, that satisfies: $\ \displaystyle\sum_{k\in K} a_k > A - \varepsilon.\ $ In general, I don't think there is a bound on $\ N,\ $ not even in terms of $\ \max\{a_k\}.\ $

Comment: If I understand correctly the question, to check if a series can be summed to a finite number, you only need to check if the “tail” of the series sums to a finite number. Hope it makes sense.